# Indexation Lag for LateX

Tags: diagrams

Good morning!

because I am using Latex the first time maybe one could help me in with this picture :)

[image]

It would be great!! Thank you so much :)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates that have you tried or what it your problem with this figure. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Also people on this site tend to not like questions that have a sense of "make this for me". Start with tikz see what you can come up with. Then update the question with the code you have come up with. With tikz this is not that hard

Comment: @Bernard Reopened as desired.

Answer (score 1):

## As the comments indicated, `Tikz` is the answer.

---

`Tikz` is one of the two primary drawing systems for `LaTeX`. The manual can be found [here](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf).

**Here is the beginning of your drawing, to give you a little jump-start:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) node[right]{Time};
        \draw (5, 0) -- (21, 0);
        \draw (5,.25) -- (5,-.25);
        \draw (8,.25) -- (8,-.25) node[pos=0,above]{Issue Date};
        \draw (18,.25) -- (18,-.25);
        \draw (21,.25) -- (21,-.25) node[pos=0,above]{Maturity Date};
        \draw [<->] (5,-.75) -- (8,-.75) node[pos=.5,above]{6 Months};
        \draw [<->] (18,-.75) -- (21,-.75) node[pos=.5,above]{6 Months};
        \draw (0,-2) node[right]{Value of the price index};
        \draw (5,-2) node{$P_{\text{issue}-1}$};
        \draw (8,-2) node{$P_{\text{issue}}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

You can see the only tools from `tikz` that I needed were:

```
\draw                             % to create a path
\draw [<->]                       % adds arrow heads
\draw (x,y) -- (x,y)              % draws a line between the ordered pairs
\draw (x,y) node[options]{text}   % adds text at the point, or along a line
```